# Jmeter - Json path Extractor - Results array not accessible

Tags: jmeter-plugins

I needed to get the leaveTypeCd where the hrsLeft > 10, used the json path extractor on the jmeter HTTP response,

Variablename: leavetypecode
JSON path : $.leaveTypes[?(@.hrsLeft>10)].leaveTypeCd
Default value : noleave

HTTP Response

```html
{
:   "leaveTypes":
:   [
:   :   {
:   :   :   "leaveTypeDesc":"Bereavement",
:   :   :   "leaveTypeCd":"ABR",
:   :   :   "earnCd":"BRV",
:   :   :   "accrualDt":null,
:   :   :   "accrualFreq":null,
:   :   :   "accrued":null,
:   :   :   "hrsLeft":null,
:   :   :   "accrualCap":null,
:   :   :   "taken":0.0,
:   :   :   "planned":0.0,
:   :   :   "projectedCapDays":null,
:   :   :   "projectedCapDate":null,
:   :   :   "planTypeDesc":null,
:   :   :   "requestList":null,
:   :   :   "balance":null,
:   :   :   "accrualRate":null
:   :   },
:   :   {
:   :   :   "leaveTypeDesc":"Sick",
:   :   :   "leaveTypeCd":"A07",
:   :   :   "earnCd":"SCK",
:   :   :   "accrualDt":"2015-03-03",
:   :   :   "accrualFreq":"Hrs/Year",
:   :   :   "accrued":40.0,
:   :   :   "hrsLeft":40.0,
:   :   :   "accrualCap":40.000,
:   :   :   "taken":0.0,
:   :   :   "planned":0.0,
:   :   :   "projectedCapDays":null,
:   :   :   "projectedCapDate":null,
:   :   :   "planTypeDesc":null,
:   :   :   "requestList":null,
:   :   :   "balance":40.00,
:   :   :   "accrualRate":40.000
:   :   },
:   :   {
:   :   :   "leaveTypeDesc":"Vacation",
:   :   :   "leaveTypeCd":"A06",
:   :   :   "earnCd":"VAC",
:   :   :   "accrualDt":"2015-03-03",
:   :   :   "accrualFreq":"Hrs/Hour",
:   :   :   "accrued":196.0,
:   :   :   "hrsLeft":200.0,
:   :   :   "accrualCap":200.000,
:   :   :   "taken":-4.0,
:   :   :   "planned":0.0,
:   :   :   "projectedCapDays":0,
:   :   :   "projectedCapDate":"2015-03-03",
:   :   :   "planTypeDesc":null,
:   :   :   "requestList":null,
:   :   :   "balance":197.99,
:   :   :   "accrualRate":0.057
:   :   }
:   ],
:   "holidaysCalendar":
:   {
:   :   "schedule":"3NQ",
:   :   "holidays":
:   :   [
:   :   ]
:   }
}
```

Json path extractor executed successfully, ${leavetypecode} has values ["A07","A06"]. But I could not access ${leavetypecode_1} and ${leavetypecode_1} to use the array values in the further calls.

Can you please help how to access the array values for further calls.

Answer (score 0):

I got to know that it was an issue with that Jmeter-plugins extras version v1.1.3. using the ExtrasLib v1.2.1 solved the issue.

I could reference the variable as variablename_arrayindex as we normally do with regex extractor or Xpath.